# Why is WebGL drawing my texture three times instead of once?

Tags: webgl

I'm attempting to build a small 2D game in WebGL and Electron. For some reason, my texture is being triple rendered when I call to render only once. I can't seem to determine why or if I'm somehow loading the texture wrong and that's triggering my issue.

The end result of my code is the following:

[image: Result of rendering]

My rendering code is as follows (`x` and `y` parameters are not used yet):

```ts
export function render(tex: texture_t, _x: number, _y: number): void {
    if (!is_valid(tex)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid value - bad texture');
    }
    if (shader_program == null) {
        shader_program = program_create_from_sources(default_v_shader, default_f_shader);
    }
    const gl = tex.context.context;
    if (index_buffer == null) {
        index_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        if (index_buffer == null) {
            throw new Error('Failed to create default index buffer');
        }
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(index_data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    } else {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
    }
    gl.useProgram(shader_program.native);
    if (vertex_buffer == null) {
        vertex_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        if (vertex_buffer == null) {
            throw new Error('Failed to create default vertex buffer');
        }
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertex_data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    } else {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    }
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shader_program.attributes.vertex_model);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader_program.attributes.vertex_model, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    if (uv_buffer == null) {
        uv_buffer = gl.createBuffer();
        if (uv_buffer == null) {
            throw new Error('Failed to create default UV buffer');
        }
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uv_buffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(uv_data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    } else {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uv_buffer);
    }
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shader_program.attributes.uv_model);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader_program.attributes.uv_model, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex.native);
    gl.uniform1i(shader_program.uniforms.texture, 0);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shader_program.attributes.uv_model);
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray(shader_program.attributes.vertex_model);
}
```

Loading code:

```ts
export function create_empty(): texture_t {
    const ctx = context_get_current();
    if (ctx == null) {
        throw new Error('Invalid operation - no rendering context');
    }
    const gl = ctx.context;
    const nat: WebGLTexture|null = gl.createTexture();
    if (nat == null) {
        throw new Error('Invalid operation - unable to create texture');
    }
    return {
        native: nat,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        source: null,
        context: ctx
    };
}

export async function create_from_image(src: string): Promise<texture_t> {
    const p = new Promise<texture_t>((resolve, reject) => {
        const tex = create_empty();
        const gl = tex.context.context;
        const img = new Image();
        img.addEventListener('load', () => {
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex.native);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
            tex.source = img.src;
            tex.width = img.width;
            tex.height = img.height;
            resolve(tex);
        });
        img.addEventListener('error', (err) => {
            destroy(tex);
            reject(err);
        });
        img.src = src;
    });
    return p;
}
```

Main function:

```ts
import * as path from 'path';
import {create as context_create, make_current} from './graphics/context';
import {texture_t, create_from_image as texture_create_from_image,
    render as texture_render} from './graphics/texture';

const ctx = context_create();
const gl = ctx.context;

make_current(ctx);

let tex: texture_t|null = null;

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

function onFrame() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (tex != null) {
        texture_render(tex, 0, 0);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
}

texture_create_from_image(`file://${path.resolve(__dirname, './images/WebGL_logo.png')}`).then((t) => {
    tex = t;
    const gl = tex.context.context;
    // HACK: Non-power-of-two, so do this.
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex.native);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    // gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with a bunch of options, I have discovered the source of the problem. It appears premultipled alpha was turned on by default (I did not specify `premultipliedAlpha: false` in my context creation options) and I had not set `UNPACK_PREMULTIPLIED_ALPHA_WEBGL` to `true`.

After forcing it off, the issue went away. Setting the above mentioned parameter to `true` via a call to `pixelStorei` also caused the issue to go away. Reverting either change causes the issue to manifest once more. I'm a little mystified as to the why this effect occurs with the default settings, but my problem is solved.